# Question link color in dark mode is hard to read

Tags: discussion, design, dark-mode

I'm usually using dark mode on every website if it's possible.
For me, on SO questions become really hard to read because of the bad contrast of link colors - so i switched back to light mode.

**EDIT:**

Updated SO Color

[Contrast validator](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=33A7FF&bcolor=404245) delivers a score of 3.89 on SO dark mode.

I'm not familiar with the corporate design of SO, but changing the link color to `#B3DEFF` would make reading a lot easier.

[Contrast validator 2](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=B3DEFF&bcolor=404245)

[image]

What is your opinion about this?

Comment: That looks very nice! The only issue here is that it compromises the accessibility (only a bit, can be handled). That's because everyone knows that [darkish-blue text](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-hyperlinks-blue-muskan-sinha) with an underline or what-not is a link that shouts "CLICK ME! CLICK ME!" and if a random guy sees that, they would most likely think that it's just text decoration.

Comment: You might be right - I adapted the color to just a slightly brighter version of the original one.

Comment: There's a "high contrast mode" where links have proper contrast and a "non-color designator" (underline) as specified in WCAG. I like to call this the "because we can't have nice things in regular contrast mode" mode.

Comment: I find that `code formatting` in a link makes it hard to read in dark mode, e.g. in this answer [Convert 16 bit mask (\_\_mmask16) to \_\_m128i control byte mask on KNL (Xeon Phi 7210)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027490) there's a bolded example near the top ([**`vpmovdb`**](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovdb:vpmovsdb:vpmovusdb) which is ok), and two non-bolded exampled near the bottom. ([`vmaskmovps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vmaskmov) which is less readable.)  That might be due to the background being even darker for code-formatting.

Comment: what would be the proposed color for the link after it has been clicked? your current proposed color seems very similar to the clicked link color.

Comment: @Nifim... I would probably do the same thing... use a slightly brighter color than the original one...maybe a little bit more blue/green.

Comment: Have faith man, devs told me they will get that full WCAG AA compliance in 4 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Why are some links darker than others?

Comment: @Marco unless that's really confirmed, what we know is [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/241919)...

Comment: Readability gets worse with "night mode" (particularly on my phone), when the screen severely shifts to the red spectrum, lowering the contrast even more. I'd fully support a higher contrast - won't go to blinding light mode on the phone. I understand that this is my own fault, but it's also yet another aspect that someone might want to pay attention to.

Comment: @AndrewT. dammit

Comment: Even with the updated color, I think it's still too subtle and easy to not realize it's meant to be a link.